# S3 Website 404 Redirection Rule not triggering over HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-certificate-manager

When I use custom domain to access S3 Website using `https://cdn.example.cz/file.png` the 404 redirection rule does not trigger, instead it ends with XML error NoSuchKey.

I have following **Redirection Rule** that is working properly when using S3 Website endpoint `http://cdn.example.cz.s3-website.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/file.png`

[image: 1]

Recently I setup CloudFront and a SSL certificate imported in Certificate Manager to serve this S3 Website on a custom domain `cdn.example.cz` over SSL (HTTPS), everything works fine, except that the `404` redirection rule does not trigger, instead it ends with XML error `NoSuchKey`.

Please note that:

- I am not using Route 53, instead `CNAME` record for `cdn.example.cz` with the value `CLOUDFRONT_SUBDOMAIN.cloudfront.net`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesDomainName).

> If the bucket is configured as a website, enter the Amazon S3 static
> website hosting endpoint for your bucket; don't select the bucket name
> from the list in the Origin Domain Name field.

As soon as I changed the origin to be the S3 website endpoint, the redirection rule triggered the Lambda function, and the response from Lambda also noticed by CloudFront.

I am not sure if that will help, but I also added following custom error response in `CloudFront Distribution` > `Error pages`.

[image]